# UIBarButtonItem - full width without flexible space

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have a UIBarButtonItem at the bottom of my screen that I want to be full width so that if the user taps anywhere in the Navigation Bar, the button will be triggered.

Currently, with flexible space on either side, the user needs to specifically click the "create set" button in the center for the button to be triggered.

[image]

However, when I remove the flexible space, I don't see a straightforward way for the text to be centered and full width.

How can I make a UIBarButtonItem full width?

Comment: You could add the same tap action to the flexible space. Or just pad the 'create set' string with equal leading/training spaces.

Comment: @thelaws adding the sent action to the flexible space is a great idea!  when I tried implementing it via the storyboard, though, it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

when you add a `UIBarButtonItem` with a width of **0** (automatic width calculation) to a `UIToolBar` in storyboard and print out it's view's frame you can see that it's **origin.x** value is **12.0**. when you change it's width to something specific (instead of automatic width calculation) and check the frame again you can see that it's **origin.x** value is **20.0**.

since in your case you have to set the width manually we will work with that value of **20.0**.

when you add two `UIBarButtonItems` to a `UIToolBar` in storyboard and print out their views' frames you can see that there is a space of **10.0** points between them.

with that values in mind you could do something like the following:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let item = UIBarButtonItem(title: "create set", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    setupToolbarWithItems([item], animated: true)

    printToolbarFrames()
}

private func setupToolbarWithItems(items: [UIBarButtonItem], animated: Bool) {
    guard let toolbar = navigationController?.toolbar else {
        print("there is no toolbar")
        return
    }

    if items.isEmpty {
        setToolbarItems(nil, animated: animated)
        return
    }

    // change item widths to specific size for correct calculation
    for item in items {
        item.width = 44
    }

    setToolbarItems(items, animated: animated)

    // calculate margin and innerItemSpace
    let firstView = items.first?.valueForKey("view") as! UIView
    let margin = firstView.frame.origin.x
    var innerItemSpace = CGFloat(0)
    if items.count > 1 {
        let secondView = items[1].valueForKey("view") as! UIView
        innerItemSpace = secondView.frame.origin.x - (firstView.frame.origin.x + firstView.frame.size.width)
    }

    // calculate and set correct itemWidth for each item
    let toolbarWidth = toolbar.frame.size.width
    let availableToolbarSpace = toolbarWidth - 2 * margin - (CGFloat(items.count) - 1) * innerItemSpace
    let itemWidth = floor(availableToolbarSpace / CGFloat(items.count))

    for item in items {
        item.width = itemWidth
    }
}
```

hope it helps :)

**EDIT**

here is another helper function to print out the relevant toolbar frames after using the `setupToolbarWithItems` method:

```
private func printToolbarFrames() {
    guard let toolbar = navigationController?.toolbar else {
        print("there is no toolbar")
        return
    }

    print("toolbar frame: \(toolbar.frame)")
    guard let items = toolbar.items else {
        print("there are no items on the toolbar")
        return
    }

    for item in items {
        let view = item.valueForKey("view") as! UIView
        print("item: \(item.title!), frame: \(view.frame)")
    }
}
```